# Returning computable numbers from WolframAlpha

Tags: string-manipulation, wolfram-alpha-queries

```
WolframAlpha["Apple company revenue", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

[image]

Desired output

> 182800000000

```
WolframAlpha["Apple company interest expense", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

[image]

Desired output

> 384000000

```
WolframAlpha["Apple company employees", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

[image]

Desired output

> 97000

```
WolframAlpha["Sony company revenue", {{"Result", 1}, "Plaintext"}]
```

[image]

**Two questions:**

(a) How can I efficiently automate this?

(b) How can I convert Sony from Yens to Dollars?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
QuantityMagnitude[WolframAlpha[#, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}]] & /@  
   {"Apple company revenue",  "Apple company interest expense", "Apple company employees"}
(* {1.828*10^11, 3.84*10^8, 97000} *)
```

**Update:** Exchange rate conversion

```
WolframAlpha[#, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}] & /@ 
  {"Sony company revenue", "Sony company interest expense"}
```

> [image]

```
UnitConvert[WolframAlpha[#, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}], "Dollars"] & /@
    {"Sony company revenue", "Sony company interest expense"}
```

> [image]

```
QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[WolframAlpha[#, {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}],
   "Dollars"]] & /@ {"Sony company revenue", "Sony company interest expense"}
(* {6.9513*10^10, 3.73491*10^9}}  *)
```

Comment: So nice! I didn't know `ComputableData`. I don't want to be overdemanding. But, how would you handle the different currencies?

Comment: @eldo,  just posted an update to handle exchange rate conversion.